# Error: cannot update, database or object read only while edit record set in another function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm passing record set from one function  (i.e.chkMismatchData) to another (CheckMismatches) and if the record is not found I update some values of passed recordset.

Even I declare variable of recordset in module level still finding the error.

My code is :

```vb
Set rec1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from CBWCFAVENDORMATCHOFFMASTER where [vendor]='" & rec![Vendor] & "'")
While Not rec.EOF        

    Set rec3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select ID,[HCI_NO],CLEARLOC,SUM([AMOUNT])AS AMOUNT1 from CBWCFAMISUPLOAD WHERE [vendor]='" & rec![Vendor] & "' and nz([match],'')='' and nz([HCI_NO],'')<>'' GROUP BY HCI_NO,CLEARLOC,ID ")
    While Not rec3.EOF

        Set rec2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select ID,DEPSLIPNO,CLEARLOC from CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA WHERE [DEPSLIPNO]='" & rec3![HCI_NO] & "' GROUP BY DEPSLIPNO,CLEARLOC,ID HAVING CLEARLOC='" & rec3![CLEARLOC] & "' AND SUM([amt])=" & rec3![AMOUNT1])
        If rec2.EOF = False Then

            If rec2.RecordCount = 1 Then
                CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE CBWCFAMISUPLOAD SET [MATCH]='Y' ,[CASHIN_ID]='" & rec2![ID] & "' WHERE [HCI_NO]='" & rec3![HCI_NO] & "'  ")
                CurrentDb.Execute ("UPDATE CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA SET [MATCH]='Y' ,[MIS_ID]='" & rec3![ID] & "' WHERE [DEPSLIPNO]='" & rec3![HCI_NO] & "'")
            ElseIf rec1.RecordCount > 1 Then
                Call UpdateRec(rec3, 0, "Duplicate Match", 0)
            End If

        Else
            strSlipType = "HCI_NO"
            Call UpdateRec(rec3, 0, CheckMismatches(rec3), 0) 'here im passing 
        End If

        rec3.MoveNext
    Wend

Wend


Private Function CheckMismatches(rec As DAO.Recordset) As String
Dim RecCheck As DAO.Recordset
Dim strDepSlipNo As String, strID As String

   If strSlipType = "HCI_NO" Then
        '--Clearing Loc Not Matching
        Set RecCheck = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select ID,DEPSLIPNO,CLEARLOC from CBWCFAPENDINGPAYMENTDATA WHERE [DEPSLIPNO]='" & rec![HCI_NO] & "' GROUP BY DEPSLIPNO,CLEARLOC,ID HAVING CLEARLOC<>'" & rec![CLEARLOC] & "' AND  SUM([amt])=" & rec![AMOUNT1])
        If RecCheck.EOF = True Then
            rec.Edit 'here i'm geting error
            rec![match]="Y"    'added line
            rec!.update 'added line
            CheckMismatches = "Clearing Loc Not Matching"
            RecCheck.Close
            Exit Function
        End If
        RecCheck.Close
end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rec3` has a `GROUP BY` clause.

A recordset that is aggregated is by definition read-only. So you have to edit the table separately from this recordset.

Why do you have `rec.Edit` in the function when you don't edit any fields of it?

Comment: please check updated code were I'm updating the records of recordset , which tagged as added line in code

Comment: Ok. But the main problem is the `GROUP BY` clause. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html -- **Why is my query read-only?** *It has a GROUP BY clause. A Totals query is always read-only.*

Comment: Thanks @Andre for such a helpful information , I will change my code accordingly,